# What are the various deployment topologies for the IBM MobileFirst Server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Using IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.0,

1. What are the various deployment topologies for the IBM MobileFirst Server?
2. When an App is deployed on the MobileFirst Server, does the app interact with the MobileFirst Server for any functions? For example when it calls a HTTP End Point using the HTTP Adapter does the call go through the MobileFirst Server (or) does it directly hit the Back End System.
3. What is the advantage of using a NoSQL DB with Mobile Apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the various deployment topologies for the IBM MobileFirst
>   Server?

You can have a single server deployment.
You can have a farm of servers.
You can have cluster(s) of farms of servers.
It can be in the cloud.

You can put a Load Balancer in front of each option above, or several. You can add an HTTP client, firewalls... it can be small, it can be huge, it can be scalable. It depends on the expected traffic volume, security considerations. It depends on IT demands.

You need to understand your needs, and based on that you can start figuring out your deployment procedures.  Some info: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_typical_topology_of_an_ibm_wor.html

> When an App is deployed on the MobileFirst Server, does the app
>   interact with the MobileFirst Server for any functions? For example
>   when it calls a HTTP End Point using the HTTP Adapter does the call go
>   through the MobileFirst Server (or) does it directly hit the Back End
>   System.

Any MobileFirst client SDK API that generates a request will go through the MobileFirst Server. This includes adapters.

Adapters are server-side entities.
The applications sends a request to the server, asking from it to generate an adapter request to the backend.

> What is the advantage of using a NoSQL DB with Mobile Apps?

Please google: https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=nosql+advantages+in+mobile+apps